# $\int_{0}^1 \ln^2 (x) / (x+1)^2 dx$ using contour integration?

Tags: logarithms, contour-integration

I am not even sure if I can apply contour integration over this. But I tired
and saw that $(z+1)^2$ gets cancelled in the denominator giving me no real part and only $-2i \pi$.

Comment: @Jean Marie. Thanks for editing this sir. I am new to this site and have yet to figure out the code signs to type this way.

Comment: For the title, type `$\int_{0}^1 \ln^2 (x) / (x+1)^2 dx$`

Comment: please go through this link https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation, which also at the bottom of the page has link to a quick reference guide that can teach you more on how to use mathjax.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: A solution without contour integration can be found [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1590253})

Comment: Sir, it says page is not found !

Comment: Without contour integration: Use the derivative of the geometric series and the integral
$$\int_0^1 x^n \log^2(x)~dx=\frac{2}{(n+1)^3}.$$
The problem rests on evaluating the sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2},$$
which is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803951/find-sum-of-alternating-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n1-n2) to be $\pi^2/6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1590267/695196) it's shown using contour integration that
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln^2(x)}{(1+x)^2}\, dx  = \frac{\pi^2}{3}
$$
Now just notice that
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln^2(x)}{(1+x)^2}\, dx  &=\int_0^{1} \frac{\ln^2(x)}{(1+x)^2}\, dx   + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^2(x)}{(1+x)^2}\, dx\\
& \overset{\color{blue}{u = 1/x}}{=}\int_0^{1} \frac{\ln^2(x)}{(1+x)^2}\, dx + \int_{1}^{0}\frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{1}{u} \right)}{\left(1 + \frac{1}{u^2} \right)} \left( -\frac{1}{u^2}\right) \, du\\
& = 2\int_0^{1} \frac{\ln^2(x)}{(1+x)^2}\, dx
\end{align}
So you can conclude that
$$
\boxed{\int_0^{1} \frac{\log^2{x}}{(1+x)^2}\, dx  = \frac{\pi^2}{6}}
$$

---

Also, in the same question linked one of the [other answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1590253/695196) gives a non-contour integration way to get the result using Taylor series. So you can also use that route if you like.

Comment: Please take a look at [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508).